# Drupal - How can I use CCK to keep a local node copy of Aggregator items?

Tags: drupal, cck, aggregators

Hey, I received an learning project from my brother that includes:

Create a Drupal site that employs Aggregator, CCK, and Views modules in the following way:

1. Aggregator will fetch an RSS feed from an arbitrary source
2. Views will allow you to create excerpts from the Aggregator materials, as well as links to orignal articles
3. Determine if there's a way to use CCK to keep a local node copy of Aggregator items--we'll want to commenting on these nodes

I'm newb, but I know how to use CCK and Views a bit. However, I don't know what he's talking about in the third part. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks for your time,

-Landon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off using the [FeedAPI module](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi) instead of the Aggregator module. FeedAPI saves incoming feed stories as nodes, and even allows you to automatically map tags on the feed items to taxonomy terms on the nodes. Commenting, compelx views, etc are all a lot easier to put together in that situation.

If you want to map some of the feed data to CCK fields, also check out the [Feed Element Mapper](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi_mapper) module. It lets you assign arbitrary chunks of the RSS or XML data to other CCK fields.

Comment: Yep, FeedAPI is the better way of doing this.